# Create a button with an icon in actionscript

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I want to create buttons with icons in Flex dynamically using Actionscript.

I tried this, with no success:

```
var closeButton = new Button();
closeButton.setStyle("icon", "@Embed(source='images/closeWindowUp.png");
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found an answer that works for me.  In my .mxml file, I create Classes for the icons I will use:

```
// Classes for icons
[Embed(source='images/closeWindowUp.png')]
public static var CloseWindowUp:Class;
[Embed(source='/images/Down_Up.png')]
public static var Down_Up:Class;
[Embed(source='/images/Up_Up.png')]
public static var Up_Up:Class;
```

In the Actionscript portion of my application, I use these classes when dynamically creating buttons:

```
var buttonHBox:HBox = new HBox();
var closeButton:Button = new Button();
var upButton:Button = new Button();
var downButton:Button = new Button();

closeButton.setStyle("icon", SimpleWLM.CloseWindowUp);
buttonHBox.addChild(closeButton);

upButton.setStyle("icon", SimpleWLM.Up_Up);
buttonHBox.addChild(upButton);

downButton.setStyle("icon", SimpleWLM.Down_Up);
buttonHBox.addChild(downButton);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this one option of dynamic change of button icon.

Embed your icons

```
[Embed(source='com/images/play.png')]
[Bindable]
public var imagePlay:Class; 

[Embed(source='com/images/pause.png')]
[Bindable]
public var imagePause:Class;
```

Using one button to toggle play and pause of video

```
private function playpause():void
{
    if (seesmicVideo.playing)
    {
        seesmicVideo.pause();
        btn_play.setStyle("icon",imagePlay);
    }
    else
    {
        seesmicVideo.play();
        btn_play.setStyle("icon",imagePause);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is in the quotes, there should be no quotes around the `@Embed`:

```
closeButton.setStyle("icon", @Embed(source="images/closeWindowUp.png"));
```

Comment: For me, this just gives the following error: `1041: Attributes are not callable.`.  I'm using Flex 3, though.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use an icon in my button with the following code:

```
<mx:Button id="buttonPlay" label="Play" click="playButtonClicked();" enabled="false" icon="@Embed('./play.png')"/>
```

the file play.png is in the same folder of the mxml file.

I am using Flash Builder version 4.6.

**Edit:** the question was about ActionScript and not MXML, but I leave this answer just for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're adding it to the stage?

Also, I think your Embed is missing a close quote / paren.

```
closeButton.setStyle("icon", "@Embed(source='images/closeWindowUp.png");
```

should be:

```
closeButton.setStyle("icon", "@Embed(source='images/closeWindowUp.png')");
```

Comment: Adding the missing close quote/paren didn't make any difference.
I still get a runtime error
Type Coercion failed: cannot convert "@Embed(source='images/closeWindowUp.png')" to Class.

I call
buttonHBox.addChild(closeButton);
Is this what you mean by add to stage?