# How to reference the image used as icon for a button in Adobe Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash-builder

I am developing a Flex application in which I would like to simulate roughly what we get when we serach Google for images. When we pass the mouse pointer over an image, it enlarges a little bit so we can see it better and click it if we want.

I *know* I could just use an image and increase its size via mouseOver/ mouseOut events, but the thing is that it is much easier for users to realise that they're clickable when I use a button with an icon (as opposed to a plain image).

So here's the question. Is there any way to alter (in this case, its height and width) the button icon through the button methods/ properties?

I can explain it a little further if this is too confusing.

Thank is advance.

P.S.: The way I'm doing it now is by changing the `src` property of the icon to switch to another (larger) version of the same picture (that requires two versions of each pictures to be stored). However, I'm using the `setStyle` method to achieve that, which, according to the documentation itself, is not very good performance-wise. And it's so much easier to adjust the size than to have to load another picture which is just an old version of the previous one.

Comment: You can give a handcursor to image using the property useHandCursor=true to give an impression to the user that it is clickable.Isnt that fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your picture is enlarged only 'a little bit', you can get away with one (larger) version (just set smoothing = true on underlying Bitmap.) This also enables smooth transition from small to larger version. And hand cursor would be fine way to indicate clickableness, while very large buttons will look strange.

Comment: Yeah. I thought about that. I'll try that.

Answer (score 1):

The question was already asked in these threads

[Create a button with an icon in actionscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300360/create-a-button-with-an-icon-in-actionscript)

[Set the icon of a Flex button with a Sprite in runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647910/set-the-icon-of-a-flex-button-with-a-sprite-in-runtime)

According to them there is no graceful solution, but the task can be done via setStyle() or using this snippet:
http://blog.benstucki.net/?p=42

The another way is to use a hack like this (Transparent button over image):

```
<s:Group width="100" height="20">
    <mx:Image source="picture_you_need.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" scaleContent="true" maintainAspectRatio="false"/>
    <s:Button id = "test_button" width="100%" height="100%" alpha="0.0"}"/>
</s:Group>
```